# Can we use the singular value decomposition to compute the matrix exponential for a non-diagonalisable matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, svd, matrix-exponential

For a diagonalisable matrix $ \bf{A} $ with eigendecomposition $ \bf{A} = \bf{U} \bf{\Lambda} \bf{U}^{-1} $, we know that $ \exp(\bf{A}) = \bf{U} (\exp \bf{\Lambda}) \bf{U}^{-1} $, where $ \exp \bf{\Lambda} $ is a diagonal matrix with $ e^{\lambda} $ terms.

I want to compute $ \exp(\bf{A}) $ where $ \bf{A} $ does not have a full set of eigenvectors (defective) so cannot use this. I tried to use the singular value decomposition by letting $ \bf{A} = \bf{U} \bf{\Sigma} \bf{V}^{T} $ and computing $ \exp(\bf{A}) = \bf{U} (\exp \bf{\Sigma}) \bf{V}^{T} $.

However, trying out a numerical example: ([SVD computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=SVD%5B%5B3%2C%20-1%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%5D%5D), [evaluating exp using SVD computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B-0.973249%2C%20-0.229753%7D%2C%20%7B-0.229753%2C%200.973249%7D%7D%20%7B%7Be%5E3.23607%2C%200%7D%2C%20%7B0%2C%20e%5E1.23607%7D%7D%20%7B%7B0.973249%2C%200.229753%7D%2C%20%7B0.229753%2C%200.973249%7D%7D%5ET)) $$ \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$ $$ \mathbf{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.973249 & -0.229753\\ 
-0.229753 & 0.973249
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \mathbf{\Sigma } = \begin{bmatrix}
3.23607 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1.23607
\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ \ \mathbf{V } = \begin{bmatrix}
0.973249 & 0.229753 \\ 
0.229753 & 0.973249
\end{bmatrix} $$
$$ \bf{U} (\exp \bf{\Sigma}) \bf{V}^{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
-24.273 & -6.456 \\ 
-4.917 & 1.9178
\end{bmatrix} $$

but the actual exponential ([computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=matrixexp%28%7B%7B3%2C-1%7D%2C%20%7B1%2C1%7D%7D%29)) should be $ \begin{bmatrix}
2e^2 & -e^2 \\ 
e^2 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
14.78 & -7.389 \\ 
7.389 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $

so something has gone wrong. Is the SVD a valid method of finding a matrix exponential, or have I just made an error somewhere?

Comment: The matrix exponential formula for the diagonalizable case works out because when you take powers of $A=U\Lambda U^{-1}$, you only collect powers on $\Lambda$. Why do you think that happens? Can you now see why this does work out for the SVD case?

Comment: I can see that $ A^n = U \Lambda^n U^{-1} $, but I don't see why we can't also use $ A^n = U \Sigma^n V^T $ by the same logic.

Comment: Actually if we do $ A^n = (U \Sigma V^{-1})^n = (U \Sigma V^{-1}) (U \Sigma V^{-1}) (U \Sigma V^{-1}) ... (U \Sigma V^{-1}) $ then I think it doesn't work because we can't simplify $ V^{-1} U $ into $ I $? Is that right?

Comment: That's right, the formula only works if $V^TU=I$. But then $U=V$ anyways.

Comment: @QuartelQuartz: I think the problem here was that above you wrote "why this does work out" but actually meant "why this doesn't work out"?

Comment: @joriki Oops, that was a typo! Yes, I meant to write "why this doesn't work out" in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As discussed in the comments, the reason this works for diagonalization is that all the factors $U^{-1}U$ in $(U\Lambda U^{-1})^n$ cancel, and thus the result is just $U\Lambda^n U^{-1}$; this doesn’t work for singular value decomposition because in that case $V^\top U$ doesn’t generally cancel in $(U\Sigma V^\top)^n$.